# Fixing "The startup disk does not have enough space to be partitioned." error in BC Assistant

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, bootcamp, partition, catalina

I'm running a Late 2014 iMac running the latest version of Catalina (10.15.3 as of 3/19/20), and I'm trying to install Windows, and **nothing**  is working.

I have a flash drive with a Windows 10 disk image on it created using BC's own support software installer, but whenever I try and install Windows Bootcamp Assistant gives me the "The startup disk does not have enough space to be partitioned" error.

I've tried turning off all Time Machine settings & running tmutil console commands to eliminate the local time machine snapshots.

[image]

After this I tried making a separate "Windows" partition using disk utility, but that won't work either. Even worse, after trying so many different solutions, I seem to have caused 200 GB or so worth of disk space to just disappear. Whenever I go into Disk Utility, it correctly shows my internal 1.12 TB drive, but the parition available to OS X is limited to 800 GB.

I've tried virtually every solution online, and to no avail. Any other solutions?

Comment: I suppose there is free space somewhere that could be use to install Windows. Could you add the output from `diskutil list` to your question? This probably will not be enough information to answer your question. In other words, after updating your question, I will have other questions.